# SQLite: mismatch argument count

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite

I use this code to get values from a database and insert in all my local sqllite/html5 tables as needed. The script will not run because it keep on giving this error:

> Number of '?'s in statement does not match argument count.

However when I output the result string using console.log and run the result in the same code block, it does get executed without any issues. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my simple code:

```
pg.get_latest_game_data = function (table_name) {

if (onlinecheck() == true) {
    $.post("http:/mysite.com/get_latest_games.php", {
        func: table_name
    }, function (data) {
        pg.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                //clear the variables upon loop
                columns = "";
                values = "";
                qs = ""


                $.each(item, function (k, v) {

                    //concatenate the strings
                    columns += "`" + k + "`,";
                    values += "'" + v + "',";
                    qs += "?,";


                });

                //remove last characters from strings
                columns = columns.slice(0, -1);
                values = values.slice(0, -1);
                qs = qs.slice(0, -1);


                console.log('tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ' + table_name + ' (' + columns + ') VALUES (' + qs + ')", [' + values + '],null,null)');

                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (" + columns + ") VALUES (" + qs + ")", ["+values+"], null, pg.onError);




            });




        });

    }, "json");
}


}
```

EDIT FOR SOLUTION: In the end I got this to work:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO "+table_name+" ("+ columns +") VALUES ("+values+")", [],null, pg.onError);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try logging you the insert statement, not the whole statement
You have

```
console.log('tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ' + table_name + ' (' + columns + ') VALUES (' + qs + ')", [' + values + '],null,null)');

tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (" + columns + ") VALUES (" + qs + ")", ["+values+"], null, pg.onError);
```

but change your log to the insert statement.

```
console.log("INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (" + columns + ") VALUES (" + qs + ")");
```

At the end of the day, the error is saying the columns you are trying to insert into doesn't match the pieces of data you are passing in.  So check the statement.

Comment: I have already spent almost one day looking on this doing all the counting to make sure they actually match and cant figure out why the actual statement does not work but the log when paste back into the code block does work. If it does not match why the log does work with out an error? Is this a sqllite bug?

Comment: Copy and paste you SQL statement that you are trying to execute (not the variables, but the actual SQL that you are trying to make work). Eg the result of console.log   Have you tried to take this SQL and execute it against your database using another tool?  Sometimes other tools will present better error messages like "missing comma"

Answer (score 0):

```
   self.db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql(query, columnsValue, function (tx) {
            // console.log(query);
            // console.log(columnsValue.join(","));

        },
        function (tx, error) {
            console.log('UPDATE error: ' + error.message);
        });

    }, function (error) {
    console.log('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function () {
    console.log('transaction ok');
    });
```